# Displaying JSON in flash

Tags: php, actionscript-3, json

I'm trying to pull data into flash using JSON but i keep getting this error

```
JSONParseError: Unexpected < encountered
 at com.adobe.serialization.json::JSONTokenizer/parseError()
 at com.adobe.serialization.json::JSONTokenizer/getNextToken()
 at com.adobe.serialization.json::JSONDecoder/nextToken()
 at com.adobe.serialization.json::JSONDecoder()
 at com.adobe.serialization.json::JSON$/decode()
 at jsonairtest_fla::MainTimeline/decodeJSON()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
 at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

even though i can runt the pp file in the browser and the ouput looks fine to me, i even tried calling up a txt file and that worked but i don't know what am i doing wrong here.

Here is AS3 code

```
 import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON

    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();


    request.url = "pull.php";
    loader.load(request);

    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, decodeJSON);


    function decodeJSON(event:Event):void{
    var loader2:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
    //trace(event.target.data);
    var People:Array = JSON.decode(loader2.data);

    trace(People[0].NETWORKNAME) ; 
    trace(People[1].NETWORKNAME) ; 

      }
```

PHP code:

```
 <?php

       $host="localhost";
       $user="";
       $password="";
       $database="db name";
       $tablename="table name";

       header('Content-type: application/json');

       if(!$connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password))
        {
            //if connection not eastablished then display message and die
            $message = mysql_error();
            //echo "$message<br>";
            die();
        }else
        // in case the connection is eastablished 
        $message = "Connection eastablished.....";
        //echo"$message<br>";
         mysql_select_db($database,$connection)
            or die("database not found");
         $query = mysql_query("SELECT NETWORKNAME from $tablename);
        $returnArray = array(); 
         while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
         array_push($returnArray, $row);

        mysql_close();
        echo json_encode($returnArray);

    ?>
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the JSON form the php output?

Comment: [{"NETWORKNAME":"abc"},{"NETWORKNAME":"xyz"}]

Comment: That's an array with json objects, not json.  A json format of that would be: {'NETWORKNAME':['abc',xyz']}

Comment: I think he's just copying the output from the page. $test = array("NETWORKNAME"=>"abc");
$test2 = array("NETWORKNAME"=>"xyz");
$output = array($test, $test2);
echo json_encode($output); will yield what he has.

Comment: Are you able to trace event.target? Elsewhere I'm looking uses event.result.

Comment: event.target.data  reveals all the php code in the output window that's about it and i still get the same error

Comment: @wajiw. That's non sense. JSON stands for Javascript Object Notation and is meant to serialized to text primitives such as Numbers, String, Booleans, etc, plus structures with named properties (like JS Objects) and integer indexed lists (like JS arrays). Returning an array of objects is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert the response into an array of undecoded JSON objects, try this:

```
var jsonArray:Array = loader2.data.match(/\{.*?\}/gi);
```

Then simply loop through calling JSON.decode on each member of the array. :)

Comment: I tried this and i get nothing

var jsonArray:Array = loader2.data.match(/\{.*?\}/gi);
var people = new Array();
for (var i=0; i<jsonArray.length; i++)
{
people[i] = JSON.decode(jsonArray[i]);
trace(JSON.decode(jsonArray[i]));

Comment: Sorry it may need to be var jsonArray:Array = String(loader2.data).match(/\{.*?\}/gi); - If that doesn't work, try tracing each property to see what's going wrong (I'd try myself but I'm in the middle of a format on my home computer!)

Comment: What do the trace statements say?

Comment: trace shows nothing  besides the first one
trace(loader2);
output:[object URLLoader]

Comment: besides when i use a txt file instead it works fine with the same formatting you know why?? this is very confusing.

Comment: It should be trace(loader2.data) - if that shows the whole lot then try var jsonArray:Array = loader2.data.match(/\{.*?\}/gi); for (var i=0; i<jsonArray.length; i++) { trace(jsonArray[i]); } and see if that gives you output

Comment: doing a trace(loader2.data) reveals all of the php code but no output

Comment: If you're getting the php code as the loader data, that's because the php isn't on a webserver, so isn't running when you call it. You'll need to either get some web hosting that supports php and put the php file online, or download and install a WAMP package on your computer and put the php file in the wwwroot directory first. Without a webserver to parse the php first, it'll be read as a plain text file! :)

Comment: i have XAMPP running on my computer and when i run the php file i get the right output. it's just some thing wrong with my AS3 code or  the way JSON is decoding in php. i don't know :(

Comment: Just want to clarify quickly, the traceloader2.data is returning the PHP code and not [{"NETWORKNAME":"abc"},{"NETWORKNAME":"xyz"}], right?

Comment: And also the location of the php file in XAMPP === /pull.php relative to the actionscript file when it's running?

Comment: yes it returns the php code not the actual output
and yes they are both residing in the same directory

Comment: OK cool, I think the solution is either that you're not running the apache webserver when running the as3 script (unlikely) or more likely that you need to put the full url to the php file in; I think it is loading it directly from the file rather than loading it via the web server. Try changing request url to however you access the php file in your web browser (e.g. http://localhost/pull.php) and it should work!

Answer (score 1):

In your php output, are you setting your header type to json?

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Your decoder may need the type to be correct.

Comment: After setting up the header i get this  [

    
      -
      {
          NETWORKNAME: "abc"
      }
    
      -
      {
           NETWORKNAME: "xyz"
      }]

Comment: That's because your format is like an array, not json.  Try using it like my comment above: {'NETWORKNAME':['abc',xyz']}

Comment: for you last line try: "echo json_encode($b, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);" (only available in PHP 5.3 though)

Comment: That's what i got after making that change                                                              [{
   -
      0: {
           NETWORKNAME: "abc"
      },
      -
      1: {
           NETWORKNAME: "xyz"
      }]

Comment: Looks like it's still pushing it as an array.  My last suggestion would be to try this class: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3195-PHP-Convert-data-from-MySQL-query-results-into-JSON.html or to try and access the object differently in your actionscript.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says there's a `<` in an unexpected position.

My guess is that you are inadvertedly reading your php from the file system, instead of running it on a server. Your file is being not executed as php code and that `<` is probably the opening tag of your php script (`<?` or `<?php`).

If you are running this code from the IDE, your url should be something like:

```
htp://localhost/my_project/pull.php
```

If you run this on a browser, you don't need an absolute path, but make sure your swf runs on an http environment (which is able to execute php, of course). That is, test it like this:

```
http://localhost/my_project/index.php
```

(where index.php is the hmtl file that embeds your swf)